# PHP cannot access MongoDB, you need to install the Mongo extension for PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu-16.04

I am new to Ubuntu and I want to use mongodb. I have installed mongodb using the command

```
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

It is working fine and showing running status. Now I want to use **moadmin** but when I open it in a browser, it shows me the message below.

```
PHP cannot access MongoDB, you need to install the Mongo extension for
PHP.
```

I also added `extension=mongodb.so` in `php.ini` which was located in `cli` and `apache2` folder. I am still seeing the same message from `moadmin.php`.

Comment: Next time you ask a question please refer to this arcticle: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

you have to install mongo php extension with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mongodb
```

Comment: try this and geeting this response php-mongodb is already the newest version (1.1.5-1~build1).